# How to change state of programmatically created animatedPositioned widget?

Tags: flutter

AnimatedPositioned widget animates when a parameter is changed (left for example). This works well unless I create it programatically. How do I change the parameters after creating it?
If you press a button it adds an AnimatedPositioned to the screen.  The 'change' button just changed the variable myLeft which should change the position but it doesn't.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    double myLeft = 20;
  List<Widget> listOfBoxes = [];
  _createRect(){
    setState(() {
      final AnimatedPositioned positioned = AnimatedPositioned(
        left: myLeft,
        top: 25,
        height: 50,
        width: 100,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        child: Container(color: Colors.black,),
      );

      listOfBoxes.add(positioned
        ,);
    });
  }
  _change(){
    setState(() {
      myLeft =200;
      print("listOfBoxes==$listOfBoxes");
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Column(
      children: [Row(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('create rect'),
            onPressed: _createRect,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('change'),
            onPressed: _change,
          ),
        ],
      ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: size.height * .7,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Stack(

            children: listOfBoxes,
          ),
        ),
    ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do not use `listOfBoxes` - instead change `myLeft` in `setState` which will rebuild `AnimatedPositioned` with new `left:`

Comment: @pskink : I want to do it programatically.  So I can add dozens of these and dispose of them individually.  So if I don't have listOfBoxes as my Stacks' children what do I use?

Comment: @pskink:  I want multiple.  But I can't get the 1st one to change.

Comment: /* var lefts = [10.0, 20.0]; */
child: Column(
children: [
Expanded(
child: Stack(
children: [
for (var i =0; i < lefts.length; i++)
AnimatedPositioned(
duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
left: lefts[i],
top: i * 100.0,
width: 100,
height: 75,
child: Container(color: Colors.red),
)
]
),
),
Row(
children: [
RaisedButton(child: Text('<<'), onPressed: () => setState(() => lefts = lefts.map((e) => e - 50).toList())),
RaisedButton(child: Text('>>'), onPressed: () => setState(() => lefts = lefts.map((e) => e + 50).toList())),
],
),
],
),

Comment: so keep in list only data, not widgets, like `lefts` array above

Comment: @pskink: Thanks!  Thats just what I needed.  I'll post the answer myself in a bit.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code doing what I asked based on pskink's comments.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var lefts = [10.0, 20.0];

  _change() {
    setState(() {
      lefts[0] = 200;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Column(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('change'),
            onPressed: _change,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: size.height * .7,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < lefts.length; i++)
                  AnimatedPositioned(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    left: lefts[i],
                    top: i * 100.0,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 75,
                    child: Container(color: Colors.red),
                  )
              ]),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('<<'),
                    onPressed: () => setState(
                        () => lefts = lefts.map((e) => e - 50).toList())),
                RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('>>'),
                    onPressed: () => setState(
                        () => lefts = lefts.map((e) => e + 50).toList())),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```